# How to move listener code from closure to method and pass arguments to it in ZF2?

Tags: php, event-handling, zend-framework2, closures

I have a `Module` class with multiple "inline" event listeners in its `onBootstrap(...)`:

```
...
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
    {
        ...
        $foo = ...;
        ...
        $halPlugin = $viewHelperManager->get('Hal');
        $halPlugin->getEventManager()->attach('bar', function ($event) {
            ...
        });
        ...
        $halPlugin->getEventManager()->attach('baz', function ($event) use ($foo)
        {
            ...
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, in order to hold/make `Module#onBootstrap(...)` slim, I want to move the listeners from the closures to separate methods. It's no problem for the `onBar` event listener. But it doesn't work for `onBaz`, that needs additional input:

```
...
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
    {
        ...
        $halPlugin->getEventManager()->attach('bar', [$this, 'onBar']);
        ...
    }
    ...
    public function onBar()
    {
        ...
    }
    public function onBaz() // <-- How to pass $foo to the method?
    {
        // Some stuff, that needs $foo...
        ...
    }
}
```

In the original variant this input was being passed into the closure via the `use` directive. But how to do this now?

**How to move the logic of an event listener (attached in the `Module#onBootstrap(...)`) from a closure with a `use` statement to a separate method and pass arguments to it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is move the foo as property of your module class
and then access it with `$this->foo`

```
class Module
{
    private $foo;

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
    {
        $this->foo = ...;
        $halPlugin->getEventManager()->attach('baz', [$this, 'onBaz']);
        ...
    }
    ...
    public function onBaz()
    {
        $this->foo
        // Some stuff, that needs $foo...
        ...
    }
}
```

You can also make the function in module return a Closure where you use `$foo` sent in with the function.

```
class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
    {
        $foo = ...;
        $halPlugin->getEventManager()->attach('baz', $this->onBaz($foo));
        ...
    }
    ...
    public function onBaz($foo)
    {
        return function ($event) use ($foo) {
            $this->foo
            // Some stuff, that needs $foo...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes, it would be technically possible and I could use it as workaroud. Nevertheless I would like to find a clean(-er) way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Move your method to a listener class.

A listener just needs to be `Callable`, which means declaring the`__invoke()` method in your class and placing all the code you have in your current `onBaz()` method

```
<?php

namespace SomeModule\Listener;

class BazListener
{

    protected $foo;

    public function __construct($foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function __invoke()
    {
         // code from onBaz() method using $this->foo
    }
}
```

You'll note that $foo is now a dependency requiring constructor injection. To fulfil the dependency write a factory for your listener class, fetch `$foo` in the factory and inject it there.

```
<?php

namespace SomeModule\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class BazListenerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
     public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $services)
     {
          //fetch foo from wherever ..
          $foo = ;
          return new \SomeModule\Listener\BazListener($foo);
     }
}
```

Now add the listener factory to the service manager so you can access it in onBootstrap

```
return array(
     'service_manager' => (
         'factories' => (
             // ..
             'SomeModule\Listener\BazListener' => 'SomeModule\Factory\BazListenerFactory',
             // ..
         ),
    ),
);
```

Finally fetch your listener as a service from the service manager in onBootstrap and attach it to your event manager

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    $bazListener = $mvcEvent->getApplication()
                            ->getServiceManager()
                            ->get('SomeModule\Listener\BazListener');
    $halPlugin->getEventManager()->attach('bar', $bazListener);
    ...
}
```

It's a bit of extra work, but it better separates concerns and you now have a standalone listener that you could potentially reuse instead of relying on a copy/pasted method from a Module class.